# Swift: Am I on the main screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm writing an iOS app in Xcode with 2 screens. I want to know if my UIView subclass is on the main screen (as opposed to the second screen), AND if it's on an iPhone (as opposed to an iPad). Is there any code that can tell me this?

Answer (score 1):

To check whether you are running in the iPad/iPhone, use the following:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
    // on iPad
} else if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
    // on iPhone
}
```

To track in which screen you are now, you can add `var` to your `view` and set it according your logic